# How do I say: “I always get stung” in French using “Je me fais piquer”?

Tags: grammaire, ordre-des-mots, adverbes

I need to know how to say “I always get stung/bitten” in French. I need it to be using *Je me fais piquer* and *toujours*. I don't know where to put *toujours*.

Answer (score 2):

"Je me fais toujours piquer" is how you properly say it.

Answer (score 2):

If the rest of the sentence is a condition, like "I always get stung when I sleep with my window open", you would say "*je me fais toujours piquer* quand je dors la fenêtre ouverte".

With less context, "*tout le temps*" would be much more common than "toujours", although slightly more familiar : "je me fais piquer *tout le temps*" or "je me fais *tout le temps* piquer". The difference in putting it before or after  the verb is quite subtle : after the verb, the emphasis is on the temporal frequency ; before the verb, it's more a relative frequency : "all the time" versus "every time". It's a question of context though, not every sentence will have that nuance, and it's not valid for other adverbial locutions.

Adverbs are, in the vast majority of cases, just after the verb they modify. Here, even though the meaning is born by "piquer", the conjugated verb is "fais". So, "je me fais piquer toujours" is wrong : the adverb is too far from its verb.

One additional note, slightly off-topic : many people understand "je me suis fait XXX" as "I had someone / something XXX me" : I asked for it. "J'ai été piqué" doesn't have that ambiguity : it's something that happened, without any incentive from you. I'm not saying you should use the passive form : "je me suis fait piquer" is much more natural in colloquial speech. However, for sensitive subjects, it's more careful to remove the ambiguity.

Comment: +1 for the final remark about ambiguity. ^-^

Answer (score 0):

`Je me fais toujours piquer` is the correct way to say it.

`Toujours`, just like any other adverb in French, is to be placed after the conjugated/infinitive verb or in the beginning of the clause (`proposition`).

Examples:

> Usain Bolt court vite. [Usain Bolt runs fast]
>
> J'aime généralement parler aux gens. [I usually like talking to people]
>
> Toujours voir avant d'y croire. [Always see it before believing it]
>
> Je suis évidemment prêt à le faire. [I'm obviously ready to do it.]

Comment: Malheureusement non. On peut en général les mettre n'importe où.

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina J'ai oublié de préciser que je parlais des adverbes verbaux, qui lorsque placés pour compléter/modifier la valeur d'un verbe, sont soit à l'attaque de la proposition, ou après le verbe (conjugué ou infinitif). Par ailleurs, `Je toujours me fais piquer` ou `je me toujours fais piquer` et même `je me fais piquer toujours` ne sont pas corrects.

Comment: @AlexandreDeAngelis non. A part les pronoms collés aux verbes qu'on ne peut pas décoller: "me fais" et "je me fais", toujours peut être mis autour de ça. je me fais piquer toujours est totalement correct.

Comment: Correct en théorie mais suffisamment inhabituel en pratique pour être perçu comme une faute.

Answer (score 0):

Le plus courant avec *toujours*:

> Je me fais toujours piquer.

Egalement possible:

> Je me fait piquer toujours.

Les adverbes peuvent se placer à peu près n'importe où, mais cela peut dépendre de leur rôle (associé au verbe, à un adjectif, à un groupe nominal).

Voir sur [wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntaxe_de_l%27adverbe_en_fran%C3%A7ais) des exemples et règles assez détaillées.